# How dangerous are alligators to people canoeing?

Tags: safety, united-states, canoes, alligators

Inspired by this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/alligator-free-mangrove-or-cypress-swamps-in-the-us), how dangerous are alligators to people out canoeing in say the Everglades in Florida?

I am sure there is some danger because from time time you here about people winning [Darwin awards](http://dailyoftheday.com/darwin-award-of-the-day-f-that-alligator/) by going swimming with alligators

What precautions should one take if canoeing in places with alligators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treat them respectfully, but there's no reason to be afraid of them.

Excerpt from http://www.kayakguide.com/Kayk-Alligators.htm

> **I Feel Safer Paddling by Alligators than Driving**
>
> Doing most of my paddling in Florida, I've encountered hundreds of alligators of all sizes on the water. And the bottom line is that I've had many more close calls driving than I've had paddling around alligators or "gators".

Crocodiles are a different situation altogether. They can be much more aggressive than their alligator cousins.

Comment: @Sherwood-Botsford, I've edited your answer to include an excerpt from the page. I've also removed the link about crocodiles, as that is a different species than the one in question. Feel free to revert or modify the changes I've made.